# How to create an installer bash script?

Tags: bash, macos, installation

Fist of all Thank you all for helping. I have tried to search and I could not find a good solution for my question.
I am trying to create an installer for mac. I have several tools that I need to install every day on mac. Here is some of them:

- git
- brew
- composer
- some git repos
- atom editor
- some apps from apple store or directly from their sites.
- etc.

Please guide me how should I start then I will start the code and put it here.

Thank you,
Amin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git and composer can be obtained from brew directly, so I'd suggest installing [brew](https://brew.sh/) first. As a start you could go with:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
# wait until that is done, eventually check if it succeeded
brew install git
brew install composer
```

and so on.